# How to pass a class instance reference as a generic type in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My objective is to create a method that would take the arguments of the buildcontext and screen reference and rout it accordingly with the provided details. My partially in complete code as bellow. help would much appreciate.

My Helper class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Utils {

 static routToPage <T> (BuildContext context,  <T> page){
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>page);
 }
}
```

The class I wants to access it

```
import './utils'
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
   navigateToPage(){
    Utils.rout(BuildContext context, PageTwo())
   }
}
```

For now as the syntax are wrong I'm stuck with my approach.

Comment: are you using this  navigateToPage(){
    Utils.rout(BuildContext context, PageTwo())
   } functiono after build method?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think no need to create static class. Here is a working example.

Paste the below method in a dart file.

```
void navigateToScreen(BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => widget,
  ));
}
```

And use the class for navigating, like

```
navigateToScreen(buildContext, YourNavigationScreen());
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using `Widget` as a object parameter instead of `<T>`.

Also you can check the easiest way navigate to another page by using route like this.

**Create Route in (yourproject)/lib/route/routes.dart**

```dart
import './page/main_page.dart';
import './page/one_page.dart';
import './page/two_page.dart';

final routes = {
  '/': (BuildContext context) => MainPage(),
  '/pageone': (BuildContext context) => PageOne(),
  '/pagetwo': (BuildContext context) => PageTwo(),
}
```

**Main Page in (yourproject)/lib/main.dart**

```dart
import './route/routes.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/', // the default route is MainPage()
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

When navigating to other page you can simply use either one of these `Navigator.pushNamed`, `Navigator.popAndPushNamed`, `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`, `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` do like this

```dart
// your can simple change the route of your choice by changing the name of route
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/pageone');
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/pagetwo');
...
```